# What is the difference between reading a file and pushing a String into a Buffer? - Node

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to consume a SSL Certificate in my node app to connect to a db.  When I put the SSL Certificate in a file and read/consume it like this, I am able to connect:

```
fs.readFile('./cert', (err, caCert) => {
    const rethink = createRethink({
        servers: [{ host, port }],
        db,
        authKey,
        ssl: { 
            ca: caCert
        } 
    });
    rethink.dbList().run().then(result => console.log(result));
});
```

So I read the certificate with `fs`, and the data that is returned is able to be consumed by my db lib.

When I try to consume it like this

```
const rethink = createRethink({
    servers: [{ host, port }],
    db,
    authKey,
    ssl: { 
        ca: new Buffer(caCert, 'utf8')
    } 
});

rethink.dbList().run().then(result => console.log(result));
```

The I get this error

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1103:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:637:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:467:38)
```

I have also tried `base64` instead of `utf8`, but that didn't work.  What is the difference between the `Buffer` and what is read in by the `fs`?  What am I missing here?

Comment: Assuming that second block of code is getting the file read in the same way as the first, I think `caCert` will be a `Buffer` already, won't it?  That said, I did this code and it looks like `new Buffer(somethingThatIsAlreadyABuffer, 'utf8')` just returns a Buffer with seemingly the same contents.  Though I wouldn't be surprised if special characters in your cert got translated slightly.  What if you do: `var buf1 = caCert; var buf2 = new Buffer(caCert, 'utf8');  console.log(Buffer.compare(buf1, buf2));`

Comment: When I compare the 2, it does not show that they are equal

Comment: So .compare() returns nonzero?  In that case, I'd probably just go through the things byte-by-byte and try to figure if there's a pattern to how they're different.  I did this exercise myself with a .png in place of your certificate, and they came out identical (.compare() returned 0).